# Solving linear equation with quadratic hadamard product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, hadamard-product

I have the following equation that I can solve iteratively, but I was wondering if it has an analytical solution that can speed up my computation.

$$ x = B(x \odot x \odot b) + a $$

where

- $x, a, b \in \mathbb{R}^D$
- $B \in \mathbb{R}^{D \times D}$

I can see that if $a = \vec{0}$ and $B = I$, that $x=b$ is a solution, but that's as far as I can get.

Comment: It's going to be difficult to beat Newton-Raphson iteration
$$\eqalign{
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\x{{\large x}}
\def\D{\operatorname{\large Diag}}
\x_{+} &= \x \;+\; \LR{\large I-2BD}^{-1} \LR{\large BDx-x+a} \\
&{\sf where}\;\;{\large D} = \D\LR{\b\odot\x} \\
}$$
I would focus on using your knowledge of the problem space to estimate a good initial value for $\x\;$